# Input Direction rtl issue with non-alphanumeric

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I don't know if it is the behavior of `direction=rtl` property of input element. When I am trying to write alphabet or number it's working in desired way, but whenever I put non-alphanumeric character, that character goes in the beginning of the value entered and after that if I enter any character then the previously entered non-alphanumeric character get placed automatically in the desired location.

What I mean is:

```
Entered a -> a
Entered ! -> !a
Entered a -> a!a
Entered @ -> @a!a
Entered a -> a!a@a
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tapas_23571113/ZNwtT/). Is it normal behavior and what is the reason behind it? Also sometimes neither `backspace` nor `delete` works.

Comment: can you add `text-align: right;`? http://jsfiddle.net/ZNwtT/2/

Comment: @EricLemos could you please give this as answer, so that I can accept it. It worked and did what I want. Thank you.

Comment: updated my comment to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `text-align: right;` instead of `direction: rtl`